# when form update, $form->isValid() failed

Tags: php, symfony

When the form is submitted, `$form->isValid()` verification fails.
The page contains `{{ form_widget(edit_form._token) }}`. But when I write `var_dump( $editForm->getErrorsAsString() )` it does not output something.
May I ask what are the reasons? Thx

In Controller:

`public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)`
`{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('shops');`

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('ShopAdminBundle:Goods')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Goods entity.');
    }
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);



    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return new Response("<script>window.close();</script>");
    }
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('gi')
       ->from('ShopAdminBundle:GoodsImage','gi')
       ->where('gi.gid = '.$entity->getId());

    $GoodsImage = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $this->render('ShopAdminBundle:Goods:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        'GoodsImage'  => $GoodsImage,
    ));
}`
```

And In View: Has fields token and Submit ~  I can't  upload template code. The Format is e..I don't know...

Comment: Did you check which field is invalid and why? It's quite difficult to tell the problem without any code.

Comment: We need to see the whole code to make sense of what you try to tell us. Is there a console error?

Comment: why you don't use symfony2 built-in profiler to debug?

Comment: I used debug.But without any error messages.

Comment: e,i find it.  in profiler, i find the forms has two form, but in view, wo just have one form.